# How Java's thread model is error prone?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading [this](http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4373170/Students-need-to-learn-multiple-programming-languages). It says that:

> Further, **Java’s thread model is low-level and error-prone**, and the
>   language’s stated objective to hide machine details is an obstacle for
>   low-level and real-time applications where such details are intrinsic
>   to the problem.

But I don't understand how Java's thread model is error prone & low level? It would be better If someone clearly explain it.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think the key thing is "low level and real time applications".  Those kinds of apps cannot tolerate a garbage collector mucking with thread execution.  Java's threading model is fine for your web app.  The point of that site is to tell students to learn more than one language.  Not meant as a knock on Java.

Comment: Please close this Question quickly before this degenerates into a language war.

Comment: @StephenC: why & how this degenerates into a language war.?

Comment: How?  When someone posts in intemperate "Answer" and someone else responds in kind.  Why?  Because people do that.

Comment: I think the statement is more about threading in general than it is about Java.  I think it's saying that threading is a low-level, and easily mis-used model for concurrent programming.  "Low-level" means, that the model is better at describing capabilities of the underlying hardware than it is at describing the needs of an application.  That's unfortunate because Java never was intended to be a low-level, "systems" programming language.  For one example of a higher-level alternative to threads, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java's basic thread model provides threads, obviously, but synchronization is implemented by a monitor with locking constructs like the `synchronized` keyword, `wait`, `notify` and `notifyAll`. These constructs are very low level. Use of these constructs requires a great deal of care, otherwise the system can be prone to race conditions, deadlocks or poor performance due to misguided locking.

However, Java provides an entire suite of much higher level concurrency constructs (`java.util.concurrent`) which are far safer and less error prone to use than the basic thread model.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize that the threading implementation of the VM is definitely *not* "error-prone", that's not what the author is saying. Threading mechanisms in Java are not faulty or bad, it is the developers' task to use them properly. Good answer!